# Solaris10: How to get the remote end IP address in inted-started bash script?

Tags: bash, solaris, solaris-10, inetd

On a Solaris 10 host there is an inetd service configured to start a bash script when it it gets an incoming TCP connection to a pre-configured port/service. Is there a way to find the IP address of the remote client in the invoked bash script?

If I was using the GNU version of inetd I would use the `--environment` command line flag. But I am using the default Solaris version of inetd/inetadm, which does not seem to support this flag. Is there a Solaris equivalent of this setting?

I also assume that `getpeername(2)` invoked on the `fd` of 0 (`stdin`) or 1 (`stdout`) would have returned the desired information but I am running a bash script and I don't seem to find a way to invoke an equivalent of `getpeername(2)` from bash.

Is my only option to invoke a C-wrapper that would do `getpeername(2)`, store it in an environment variable (or a command-line argument), and invoke the main bash script?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get them by parsing `pfiles` output, something like:

```
pfiles $$ | grep peername | head -1 | nawk '{print $3}'
```

Edit:

Here is a lighter way in reply to Nemo's right comment about the number of processes launched:

```
pfiles $$ | nawk '/peername/ {print $3;exit}'
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick and comprehensive answer! I took is a little step further by tightening up the grep pattern and using `cut` instead of `nawk`.

Answer (score 2):

You can invoke [getpeername](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/getpeername.html) from a Perl one-liner:

```
perl -le 'use Socket; ($port,$addr) = sockaddr_in(getpeername(STDIN)); print inet_ntoa($addr);'
```

Wrap in backticks or whatever to run from a shell script.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! It would work but it looks a little heavier than the `pfiles $$` approach offered by jlliagre. Thanks again!

Comment: I would not be so sure about "heavier".  My answer is one extra process instead of four...  Anyway, glad you have your answer :-)